# Excel Jet SQL, IIF limitations

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I am using excel to jet sql query internally between worksheets.
But when I apply more than 10 iif statements in a query I think Jet SQL does not allow this.

Is there a way around this? I need to do +10 iif statements within my query.

Here is my code,

```
   iif(([overflow$].[business_name] = 'GELP') AND ([stack$].[level] = 'Component'),[stack$].[componentidentifier1], 
iif(([overflow$].[business_name] = 'GELP') AND ([stack$].[level] = 'Package'),[stack$].[packageidentifier1], 
iif(([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'EQUITY')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Equity - Common Stocks'), [stack$].[enterprisereportinglocalexchangesymbol], 
  iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'EQUITY') 
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Equity - Receipts'),[stack$].[enterprisereportinglocalexchangesymbol], 
  iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'EQUITY') 
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Equity - Rights'),[stack$].[reportingcusip],
iif  (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'EQUITY') 
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Equity - Warrants'), [stack$].[reportingcusip], 
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'EQUITY') 
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Equity- CLOSED Trust Units, Income Trusts'),[stack$].[enterprisereportinglocalexchangesymbol], 
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'EQUITY') 
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Equity- REIT'), [stack$].[enterprisereportinglocalexchangesymbol] ,
iif  (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS' AND [stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'EQUITY' 
AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Exchange Traded Fund (ETF)'), [stack$].[enterprisereportinglocalexchangesymbol] ,
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'EQUITY') 
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Partnership'), [stack$].[enterprisereportinglocalexchangesymbol] ,
iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Bond - Sovereign Agencies and Guarantees ( GSE, Sovereign Agencies, Federal Crown Corps)'), [stack$].[reportingcusip] ,
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Bond - Sovereigns'),[stack$].[reportingcusip] , 
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Bond - Supranationals and Multilateral Development Banks'), [stack$].[reportingcusip] ,
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Bonds - Agencies or Guaranteed by State, Provinces, Semi-Governments (excluding all Municipals)'),[stack$].[reportingcusip] ,
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Bonds - Corporate - Financial'), [stack$].[reportingcusip],
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Bonds - Corporate - Non Financial'),[stack$].[reportingcusip] ,
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME') 
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Bonds - Covered'),[stack$].[reportingcusip] ,
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME') 
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Bonds - Municipals - and their Guarantees and Agencies (excluding US Municipals)') ,[stack$].[reportingcusip] , 
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Bonds - Non-Soveriegn Governments - State, Provinces, Semi-Governments (excluding all Municipals)'),[stack$].[reportingcusip] ,
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Bonds-Securitized-Asset Backeds'), [stack$].[reportingcusip],
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Convertibles'),[stack$].[enterprisereportinglocalexchangesymbol] ,
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Money Market - Cash: Sovereign Treasury Bill'), [stack$].[reportingcusip] ,
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'FIXED INCOME')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Preferred Shares'), [stack$].[enterprisereportinglocalexchangesymbol] ,
 iif (([overflow$].[business_name] = 'EQUITY MARKETS') AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype2] = 'Shares')
 AND ([stack$].[componentsecuritytype1] = 'Equity'), [stack$].[enterprisereportinglocalexchangesymbol], 'DamN' ))))))))))))))))))))))))),
```

Sample data and 'new col' represents the expected output. I was able to run my iif command for the first 3 iif's in my sql statement above. This is a sample output. I need be able to run all my above case/iif statements.

```
+---------+---------+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| New col |  level  | packageidentifier1 | componentidentifier1 | business_name  |
+---------+---------+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| SGD/USD | Package | SGD/USD            |                      | GELP           |
| CAD/USD | Package | CAD/USD            |                      | GELP           |
| CAD/USD | Package | CAD/USD            |                      | GELP           |
| USD/INR | Package | USD/INR            |                      | GELP           |
| CAD/USD | Package | CAD/USD            |                      | GELP           |
| CAD/USD | Package | CAD/USD            |                      | GELP           |
| GBP/EUR | Package | GBP/EUR            |                      | GELP           |
| HKD/CNY | Package | HKD/CNY            |                      | GELP           |
| EUR/JPY | Package | EUR/JPY            |                      | GELP           |
| CHF/CAD | Package | CHF/CAD            |                      | GELP           |
| USD/EUR | Package | USD/EUR            |                      | GELP           |
| GBP/CHF | Package | GBP/CHF            |                      | GELP           |
| SEK/GBP | Package | SEK/GBP            |                      | GELP           |
| GBP/EUR | Package | GBP/EUR            |                      | GELP           |
| GBP/EUR | Package | GBP/EUR            |                      | GELP           |
| USD/CNY | Package | USD/CNY            |                      | GELP           |
| DamN    | Package | Stack              |                      | EQUITY MARKETS |
| DamN    | Package | Stack              |                      | EQUITY MARKETS |
| DamN    | Package | Stack              |                      | EQUITY MARKETS |
| DamN    | Package | Stack              |                      | EQUITY MARKETS |
| DamN    | Package | Stack              |                      | EQUITY MARKETS |
| DamN    | Package | Stack              |                      | EQUITY MARKETS |
| DamN    | Package | Stack              |                      | EQUITY MARKETS |
| DamN    | Package | Stack              |                      | EQUITY MARKETS |
| DamN    | Package | Stack              |                      | EQUITY MARKETS |
| USD/CLP | Package | USD/CLP            |                      | GELP           |
+---------+---------+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: If you find yourself nesting `IIf` more than about three statements deep, there's almost definitely a better way of doing it. But we don't know what that is if we can't see your code.

Comment: @jsheeran , yes I am trying to do around 20 IIF statements within my query, not really sure how to tackle the issue though.

Comment: If you show an example of the type of data you'll be using and what the requirements are no doubt someone will come up with a way of doing it _without_ using nested `IIF` statements.  As @jsheeran said - if you're using that many then you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: What does "Doing 10 iif statements?" mean. All in one column (nested) or a one per column. Share some code for goodness sake.

Comment: Sorry, added it. Yes this is creating one new column and will be all in one.

Comment: That is nightmarish. I suspect you are trying to solve a problem using nested iif that is best solved through some other means (like a UNION query or a pivot table). Even if you could Access to accept many levels of nested iif, I'm not sure that you would want to. The  maintenance of this code would be hell. Could you share some sample data and your desired results and perhaps we could help towards a more reasonable solution.

Comment: ^ Indeed. [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: You're looking for the [Switch function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379). That will allow you to make the code considerably less horrible

Comment: i have updated the question with sample data

Comment: Does anyone think this could be turned into an IF formula ? with ANDs and ORs. ill give it a try